# Defining decimal property - decimal (18,2)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, decimal, data-annotations

I need help mapping a property for a `decimal (18,2)` column in my Model.
I tried just using a .Net `decimal`, but when I type e.g. `12.12` in the input field this number will be saved as `1212,00`.

```
public decimal Ocjena1 { get; set; }
```

I can't find a solution for this. How should I declare the property in my model to match this column?

Comment: public decimal Ocjena1 { get; set; }  is this property in my Model

Comment: What do you mean by mapping? Are you using an ORM like Entity Framework? If so you need to provide either attribute or fluent mapping and specify the precision/scale. Where/How you do this depends on the ORM.

Comment: I use Entity Framework and everything works fine, i have only problem with correct mapping data in database. I tried with [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]  but it doesn work

Comment: Also, i tried with adding:  modelBuilder.Entity<Norma>()
            .Property(s => s.Ocjena1).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)"); in my Context

Comment: Please add an [mcve] as there is not enough information to determine where/why your code is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.` is not recognized by your browser culture, it uses `,` instead of `.` to represent number.

It works well when I use `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]`on the field until I change my app culture to support `hr` which uses comma instead of dot to represent data and set Croatian as the top of browser language.Then I have the same situation.

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("hr"),
        };

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
//other middlewares
app.UseMvc()
```

Try to check your app culture and browser ordered culture.You also need to type `12,12` if you are using comma.